# Split string at each occurrence of delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, jet

I need to split this string into multiple fields at the occurrence of each delimiter as shown below:

```
Display Value
466500-GO-INF-ITAPPS-EMP-CLERADM

Main Account  Business Unit   Department Cost Center   Asset Type   Classification
466500        GO              INF        ITAPPS        EMP          CLERADM
```

I currently am using the query below to remove the characters before the "-":

```
stuff([DISPLAYVALUE], 1, charindex('-', [DISPLAYVALUE]), '')
```

I then execute this query to return the characters before the "-":

```
case

when charindex('-',[DISPLAYVALUE])>0

then Substring([DISPLAYVALUE], 1, Charindex('-', [DISPLAYVALUE])-1)

else [DISPLAYVALUE]

end
```

Unfortunately this results in multiple helper columns. Is there a way to achieve this solution in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output converting your string to XML and then taking advantage of XML type methods such as `VALUE` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)) to extract the information you need:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE ([DISPLAYVALUE] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @mockup
VALUES ('466500-GO-INF-ITAPPS-EMP-CLERADM')

;WITH Splitted
AS (
    SELECT  
         CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([DISPLAYVALUE], '-', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
    FROM @mockup
    )
SELECT
     Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'int')         as [Main Account]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(50)') as [Business Unit]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(50)') as [Department]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[4]', 'varchar(50)') as [Cost Center]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[5]', 'varchar(50)') as [Asset Type]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[6]', 'varchar(50)') as [Classification]
FROM Splitted;
```

Result:

[image: Result grid]

The first select statement:

```
SELECT  
     CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([DISPLAYVALUE], '-', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
FROM @mockup
```

converts your string into an XML document with a sequence of XML tags (named `<x>`, but you could have used anything else here), each of them containing one of your values:

```xml
<x>466500</x>
<x>GO</x>
<x>INF</x>
<x>ITAPPS</x>
<x>EMP</x>
<x>CLERADM</x>
```

Now in the second select statement you can use specific XML type operators such as `VALUE()`  to get each value from the XML and put it in a separate column:

```
SELECT
     Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'int')         as [Main Account]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(50)') as [Business Unit]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(50)') as [Department]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[4]', 'varchar(50)') as [Cost Center]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[5]', 'varchar(50)') as [Asset Type]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[6]', 'varchar(50)') as [Classification]
FROM Splitted;
```

here you are using an XQuery to extract a single value from the XML document created in the first select.

For example to extract the content of the first tag `<x>` you use the XQuery `'/x[1]'` to retrieve the first element, `'/x[2]'` for the second and so on.

Comment: Andrea, I am not familiar with XML. Could you explain the two SELECT statements?

Comment: @amcneil206 sure, I have added a few details to explain what is happening in each select. Hope this helps to shed some light.